# List of files to commit into Repository after we create Maven Dynamic web Project?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, pom.xml

According to my understanding when we create a Maven-> Dynamic Web Project. There are multiple files get created among which most of them are Eclipse or your machine specific. I need to understand what are the files we need to commit so that it works perfectly fine when imported by any other developer.

**Below is my project structure and files for first commit.**

1. Files for the First Commit.

[image: Files for the First Commit]

2. Project Facets

[image: Project Facets]

Comment: all the files starting  org.eclipse.*   and  .*    should not be committed

Comment: u shuld not commit GIT and Eclipse related files which is gitignore classpath .project menifest